# Why does input.nextint method have a \n as a leftover?

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

In the answer to this question I don't understand why the `input.nextInt` has a newline character as a leftover.

[Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is quite simple:

`Scanner#nextInt()` reads the next integer but not the newline (`ENTER`) the user presses to submit the integer.

To understand this you must know that everything you type will be written to a buffer, from which the `Scanner` methods try to read from.

---

Regard the following example:

```
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
int i = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter a line: ");
String l = scanner.nextLine();
```

What will happen:

- The user sees `Enter a number:` and will press `17` and `ENTER`.
- The scanner will read the `17` but leave the newline of the `ENTER`.
- The program will write `Enter a line:` but the scanner will read the newline of the `ENTER` instead of waiting for input.

Comment: why does this not happen when I submit input.nextLine ?

Comment: `nextLine(...)` reads all input until a newline character is found. That newline character will then be consumed

Answer (score 1):

This is purly a design decision, the reason `nextInt()` doesn't consume the newline character, is because there may be some other tokens that haven't been parsed yet, it would be most inappropriate to assume there's nothing left in the string, and consume the newline char.

For instance, you are given the following input

`123 123 \n`

Calling `nextInt()` will result in the following string left in the buffer

`123 \n`

Calling `nextInt()`again,

`\n`